# Enabling Unconstrained Delegation on Active Directory Domains

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, kerberos, delegation

Where can i see the setting in domain , if i enable "unconstrained Delegation" by using below command?

**`netdom.exe trust fabrikam.com /domain:contoso.com /EnableTGTDelegation:Yes`**

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell module for Active Directory.

```
Get-ADTrust -Filter *

Direction               : BiDirectional
DisallowTransivity      : False
DistinguishedName       : CN=litware.com,CN=System,DC=contoso,DC=com
ForestTransitive        : False
IntraForest             : True
IsTreeParent            : False
IsTreeRoot              : False
Name                    : litware.com
ObjectClass             : trustedDomain
ObjectGUID              : 10233929-969d-453f-aaea-1a73f7659e74
SelectiveAuthentication : False
SIDFilteringForestAware : False
SIDFilteringQuarantined : False
Source                  : DC=contoso,DC=com
Target                  : litware.com
TGTDelegation           : True
TrustAttributes         : 32
TrustedPolicy           :
TrustingPolicy          :
TrustType               : Uplevel
UplevelOnly             : False
UsesAESKeys             : False
UsesRC4Encryption       : False
```

Comment: Thank you, there is little confusion; the status "TGTDelegation           : True" means the delegation is disabled? and if its set to "False" its enabled? This confuses me a little, why the other way?

Comment: No, True means it TGTDelegation is enabled. The secure state is False/No. False/No is also the default after the July 2019 update is installed.  See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4490425/updates-to-tgt-delegation-across-incoming-trusts-in-windows-server .

Comment: I am referring to this article;                                                                           
               The value returned from the above command is counterintuitive and is backwards from what you might expect:

FALSE – A return of false means that the delegation is enabled and is in the unsafe state.
TRUE – A return of true indicates that the delegation is disabled and is in the safe state.                  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2019/04/11/changes-to-ticket-granting-ticket-tgt-delegation-across-trusts-in-windows-server-askpfeplat-edition/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to make a comment, so I'm going to post this as an answer:

When you enable TGT delegation via `netdom trust x /domain:y /EnableTgtDelegation:Yes` (which is unsafe) then `Get-ADTrust` shows `TGTDelegation : True`.

When you disable TGT delegation via `netdom trust x /domain:y /EnableTgtDelegation:No` (which is safe) then `Get-ADTrust` shows `TGTDelegation : False`.

This is on Windows Server 2019 Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.2061) with WSUS updates applied as of July 2021.

This disagrees with the comment @Darktux made on the other answer.